LWC FlexcardMixin interpolateWithRegex
I am attempting to connected a Custom Event to a Flexcard embedded in an LWC with FlexcardMixin, but I cannot find any documentation/examples of the methods used with OmniScriptbaseMixin
It seems this component is auto-generated by creating and activating a Flexcard. Is it expected that I should modify the LWC? Or is the Flexcard only in the OmniStudio UI?
export default cfAccount_Selector extends FlexcardMixin(OmniscriptBaseMixin(LightningComponent){
  pubsubEvents = [];
  

  connectedCallback(){ 
    super.connectedCallback();
    this.registerEvents();
  }

  registerEvents(){
       // assuming I'm adding the event handler to the card
       this.pubsubEvent[0] = {
         [interpolateWithRegex(`cacheloaded`, this._allMergeFields, this._regexPattern, "noparse")]: this.handleEventsAction(this, data.events[0], 0)
       };

       // add the channel my-case called `mychannel`
       this.pubsubChannel = interpolateWithRegex(`mychannel`, this._allMergeFields, this._regexPattern, "noparse");
       
       // register with pubsub 
       pubsub.register(this.pubsubChannel, this.pubsubEvent[0]);
    } 
  
}

I don't know where the documentation for interpolateWithRegex is, but I'm trying to have the card reload or trigger an action when the event is received.
Also, I'm not sure if it's possible to have a Flexcard delay loading data until the event is received. The "Data Source" is currently defined as an IP, but I would prefer it if it just took the data from the event.
